# Is there a Script to create a hyperlink within a column whenever a new row is created in Gsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am importing information into my Google Sheet which creates a new row automatically. Basically I need a script that when a new row is created, a hyperlink for cell 'V' appears in cell V.

Ive tried using only Google formulas as I have no scripting experience

I have no code sorry, I am a total Noob

Basically I need a script that when a new row is created, a hyperlink for cell 'V' appears in cell V of the new row.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using arrayformula? `=arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,hyperlink(A2:A,"link label")))`

If you put this at the top of the spreadsheet, it will create hyperlinks for all of those URLs.
Maybe a spreadsheet example would help?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lNfR-G_T7M5d8xi-UK1lLJGGJnxNox6iZYG0eykKV9I/edit#gid=0
If I'm still not understanding, feel free to edit that spreadsheet to make it more accurate for your specific case.